# how to round the corners of a AlertDialog by code

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components, material-components-android

I have the following code, which creates me a alertdialog containing a webview.
How can I set the corners to be rounded by code ?

```
public QuickTextViewer(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    webView = new WebView(context);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.loadData("No Text", "text/html", "utf-8");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    alert.setView(webView);

    // Dialog
    dialog = alert.create();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.END);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) which configures the instantiated `AlertDialog` with Material specs.

You can apply a custom [**`ShapeAppearanceModel`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/ShapeAppearanceModel).
Something like:

```
 MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder = 
         new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context).setTitle("Dialog")
            .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null);

 float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);

 // Set a custom ShapeAppearanceModel
 MaterialShapeDrawable alertBackground = (MaterialShapeDrawable) materialAlertDialogBuilder.getBackground();
 alertBackground.setShapeAppearanceModel(
          alertBackground.getShapeAppearanceModel()
          .toBuilder()
          .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius16)
          .build());

 materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
```

[image]

It requires the version **1.1.0**.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long way but it's the perfect solution, create a new drawable file and write this code

**circle.xml (it's store in drawable file)**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners
    android:radius="100dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#E6E4E0"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#B48B05"/>
```

After that, create a layout file for your Dialog layout and use the file above as your background E.g

```
 android:background="@drawable/circle"
```

Now create a Dialog Class to implement your layout

**DialogClass.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DialogClass extends Dialog
        implements  android.view.View.OnClickListener{

public Activity c;
public Dialog d;
public Button SETTINGS, OK;

public No_Internet(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    this.c = a;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
    SETTINGS = findViewById(R.id.btnsettings);
    OK = findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

    SETTINGS.setOnClickListener(this);
    OK.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnOK:
            dismiss();
            break;

        case R.id.btnsettings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
            c.startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    dismiss();
    } 
 }
```

**So when you want to use this dialog just use this**

```
 DialogClass dialog = new DialogClass(activityName.this);
 internet.show();
```

Comment: There should be a way but I always use this custom dialog instead of that AlertDialog.. When using this, You can specify how your layout will be